# Alter sequence for all sequences to all column with max id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sequence

I am trying to create a stored procedure that dynamically restarts all sequences in one specific schema with the max value of 1 column for each table.

Something like this:

```
alter sequence @schema.@sequence 
   restart with 
     select max(@column) 
     from @table
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    t.name, c.name 
FROM 
    sys.tables t         
INNER JOIN 
    sys.all_columns c  ON c.object_id = t.object_id          
INNER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id  = t.schema_id         
WHERE 
    t.name = @table         
    AND c.name = @column        
    AND s.name = @schema  -- to find the table with column the sequence is used

SET @sql_max = 'SELECT MAX(' + @column + ') FROM ' + @table 

--to find the max value to restart the sequence
SET @sql_text = 'ALTER SEQUENCE ' + @schema + '.' + @sequence
          + ' RESTART WITH ' + @start_value
          + ' INCREMENT BY 1
              MINVALUE 0
              MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
              CACHE  100000;';
-- to restart the sequence with max value I currently selected
```

I don't know how to set the `@start_value` for each table and column.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It looks like you are trying to set your sequence to the max value in some table? How do you ensure that the value would be correct? There is nothing that says a given sequence can be used for only 1 table. What table's max value would you choose? If you can explain what you are actually trying to do we can help.

Comment: WE use for each table 1 sequence. Currently we migrate from Oracle to MS SQL Server. So we have to start new sequences. But because of more environments we want to do it dynamical.
I want a Stored Procedure where i just say what sequence name, schema name, table name and column I have and as a result the sequence is altered to the next higher value from the already existing Table with files in it

Comment: So you need to figure out which table goes with what sequence then. I can't help you there because that is some sort of naming convention you have. Having a sequence for every table seems like a maintenance nightmare to me. Why not just use the identity property since each set of values is isolated to a single table?

Answer (score 3):

Simple SQL can do the trick

```
GO
DECLARE @seq NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @seq = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name) + 1;
SET @sql = 'ALTER SEQUENCE sequence_name RESTART WITH ' + @seq  
EXEC (@sql)
GO
```

Replace table_name and sequence_name with your table/sequence.